# Lightning component to display records based on selected static picklist value

Tags: lightning

Please help me how to display Account records based on selected picklist value. If picklist value "Banking" is selected then only those Account should be displayed which Industry is Banking, if Non Banking is selected then those Account records should be displayed which Industry type is other than Banking.

```
Apex:

    public class CustomListView {
        @AuraEnabled
        public static List <Account> fetchAccounts() {
            List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id, Name, BillingState, 
                                        Website, Phone, Industry, Type from Account];
            //return list of accounts
            return accList;
        }
    }

Component:

<aura:component controller="CustomListView">

    <aura:attribute type="Account[]" name="acctList"/>
    <aura:attribute name="mycolumns" type="List"/>

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.fetchAcc}"/>

    <br/>

    <lightning:select name="cStat" label="select a value" value="New" aura:id="statusPicklist" >
        <option value="All">All</option>
        <option value="Banking">Banking</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </lightning:select>

    <br/><br/>
    <lightning:datatable data="{! v.acctList }"
                         columns="{! v.mycolumns }"
                         keyField="id"
                         hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>



</aura:component>


Controller:

({
    fetchAcc : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.fetchAccHelper(component, event, helper);
    },

    onChange: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        var selectedPicklistValue= component.find("statusPicklist").get("v.value");
        alert("selectedPicklistValue ==>" +selectedPicklistValue)

    }

})

Helper:

({
    fetchAccHelper : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.mycolumns', [
            {label: 'Account Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'},
                {label: 'Industry', fieldName: 'Industry', type: 'text'},
                {label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone', type: 'Phone'},
                {label: 'Website', fieldName: 'Website', type: 'url '}
            ]);
        var action = component.get("c.fetchAccounts");
        action.setParams({
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.acctList", response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})

App:

<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <c:CustomListView/>
</aura:application>
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me. Do you only have two types of Accounts? How do you want to initialize the component? Do you want all accounts to display or "None" until you select the type of Account? If you use "All", then it's simply a matter of removing the selected type of records from your original list and returning the New Type of List without having to run another query (much faster too).

Answer (score 2):

Shared code requires many changes as below:

1.)Apex Controller :
Since you need to fetch accounts based on industry , it needs to be passed to apex

```
public class CustomListView {
        @AuraEnabled
        public static List <Account> fetchAccounts(String accountType) {//Pass accountType from lightning 
            List<Account> accList = new List<Account>():
            //query based on passed value  
            if(String.isNotBlank(accountType)){
            accList = [SELECT Id, Name, BillingState,Website, Phone, Industry, Type from Account WHERE Industry =:accountType];
           }
           else{
                 //add limit according to your requirement or implement pagination
                 accList = [SELECT Id, Name, BillingState,Website, Phone, Industry, Type from Account LIMIT 5000];
           }
            //return list of accounts
            return accList;
        }
    }
```

2.) Lightning component:
  Here , we can declare a attribute to store account type ,bind it with lightning:select and initialize it with blank value.Also , call controller function on change of picklist selection.

```
<aura:component controller="CustomListView">

    <aura:attribute type="Account[]" name="acctList"/>
    <aura:attribute name="mycolumns" type="List"/>
    <aura:attribute name="accountType" type="String" default=""/>

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/><!-- Added init event -->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.fetchAcc}"/>

    <br/>

    <lightning:select name="cStat" label="select a value" value="{!v.accountType}" aura:id="statusPicklist" onchange="{!c.fetchAcc}">
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option value="Banking">Banking</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </lightning:select>

    <br/><br/>
    <lightning:datatable data="{! v.acctList }"
                         columns="{! v.mycolumns }"
                         keyField="id"
                         hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>



</aura:component>
```

3.) Lightning helper:
Here , pass accounttype value to apex by setting action parameters as below :

```
({
    fetchAccHelper : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.mycolumns', [
            {label: 'Account Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'},
                {label: 'Industry', fieldName: 'Industry', type: 'text'},
                {label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone', type: 'Phone'},
                {label: 'Website', fieldName: 'Website', type: 'url '}
            ]);
        var action = component.get("c.fetchAccounts");
        action.setParams({"accountType":component.get("v.accountType")});// pass account type to apex 
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.acctList", response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

4.) Lightning Controller:

Add "doInit" method and pass blank value in "accountType" so as to fetch all records as written in apex.Also , set accounttype attribute to blank on initial load.

```
({
    fetchAcc : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.fetchAccHelper(component, event, helper);
    },

    onChange: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        var selectedPicklistValue= component.find("statusPicklist").get("v.value");
        alert("selectedPicklistValue ==>" +selectedPicklistValue)

    },

    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
       helper.fetchAccHelper(component, event, helper);
    }
})
```

I have not tested it , but this is just to give you an idea of how to pass account type and query based on value passed from lightning component.Also , clarity is needed if all accounts needs to be fetched for none value.

Comment: Yes Rohit. when page is loaded for first time then all Accounts should be displayed. And when Banking is selected, only Banking accounts should be displayed and non banking selected, then all accounts which are not banking should be dspalyed.It should happen on selecting picklist value since I am not using any search button. But currently functionality is not working

Comment: @SFDCLearner , I have updated my answer as per your description . Please mark it as the answer if it helps you.